# Flask equivalent for the .Net Framework or C#

Tags: c#, .net, web, flask

Is there any equivalent of Python's Flask web programming framework that exists for C# or .Net?  Right now I'm wanting to learn more about C# because I found that I enjoyed working on it with a separate project, and now I want to try writing a web application in it.

Comment: If you improve this question, it will be valid on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

It is note valid on SO, as it is a recommendation question.

Comment: If you know both Python/Flask and C#/WCF, that's exactly how you'd formulate your question. The answer below, Nancy, is also perfect. This question/answer pair does what it's intended, and helps (at least a subset of) developers find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) will be the closest thing to Flask since it's an MVC but it's loaded with a bunch of stuff where Flask is a micro framework.</strike>

Edit: On @emodendroket's suggestion [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) seems to be a great fit for a light weight web framework.

Comment: Nancy is probably lighter but I don't know anything about Flask.

Comment: I'm reading the doc know I like what I see!

Comment: Looks like Nancy fits the bill exactly!

Comment: Looks like Nancy is no longer maintained